# CSS ? selector is not working with SCSS selector

Tags: css, sass

I need to select previous sibling. And to do that I am referring to this link.
https://dev.to/ritvikdubey27/sibling-selectors-in-css-33k

This the code snippet:

```
 p:hover ? h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
 }
```

It is working fine in CSS but when I add it to my react project with SCSS support, it is not working. And I am not able to find any documentation or reference link to fix this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such `?` selector in CSS are you loading the library correctly?

Comment: @Paulie_D Seems like we do have a selector `?`. He is the codepen with this selector
https://codepen.io/ritvikbunny/pen/abNyRgJ

Comment: That selector uses a javascript library

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that react's scss compiler doesn't recognize the ? selector so it discards it.
Try to first compile the scss manually without the ? selector (to avoid errors) and then add it to the compiled css and use it as regular css.
and of course add `<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>`
for axe support.